# Setting a parameter from a view (best practice)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a view (index.html.erb), I have a list of all my articles:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
...
 <%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %>
 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %>
 <%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
...
<% end %>
```

And I would like to make a link (that only admins see), where the admin can set the article-attribute 'illegal' to be true/false. Something along these lines:

```
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
 <%= link_to "Mark as illegal", article, :method => "set_article_as_illegal" %>
<% end %>
```

This obviously doesn't work. But I don't know how to do this, in the best way. The only way I can think of, is really clumsy (Option B from below).

The way, that I think it should be done (or at least something along those lines).

**A) Making two helper-functions as such:**

```
def set_article_as_illegal(article)
  article.update_attribute :illegal, true
end

def set_article_as_legal(article)
  article.update_attribute :illegal, false
end
```

And somehow calling them like such:

```
<%= link_to "Mark as illegal", article, :method => "set_article_as_illegal" %>
```

... But I don't know how to make a link (or a button) that performs a method and takes an input (which should be the article in this case).

**B) Making a new controller (or a bunch of them) to do it.**

This just seems so wrong, but it's the only way, where I would be able to achieve what I want to achieve at this given point, which is why I mention it. So it would mean:

- Making a route: `get '/make_article_illegal', to: 'article#make_illegal'`
- Making another route: `get '/make_article_legal', to: 'article#make_legal'`
- Making a controller `make_illegal` that handles making it illegal.
- Making another controller `make_legal` that handles making it legal.

But this seems sooo clumsy.

There must be an obvious way to do this, that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are endless (almost) ways of doing this of course. One way is to.

```
# routes.rb
get '/update_article_legality/:id/:illegal' => 'article#update_legality', as: :update_article_legality

# in the view
= link_to 'Make legal',   update_article_legality_path(id: article.id, illegal: 'false')
= link_to 'Make illegal', update_article_legality_path(id: article.id, illegal: 'true')

# in controller
def update_legality
  article = Article.find(params[:id])
  illegal = params[:illegal] == 'false' ? false : true

  article.update_attribute :illegal, illegal
end
```

Another way and more of an MVC one is to actually create two controllers with just one method each to update the legality. Maybe this is overkill for your situation but this is the theory at least.

```
# app/controllers/article/illegal_controller.rb
class Article::IllegalController < ApplicationController
  def update
    article = Article.find(params[:id])
    article.update_attribute :illegal, false
  end
end

# app/controllers/article/legal_controller.rb
class Article::LegalController < ApplicationController
  def update
    article = Article.find(params[:id])
    article.update_attribute :illegal, true
  end
end

# routes.rb
get '/make_article_legal' => 'article/legal#update', as: :make_article_legal
get '/make_article_illegal' => 'article/illegal#update', as: :make_article_illegal

# in the view
= link_to 'Make legal',   make_article_legal_path(id: article.id)
= link_to 'Make illegal', make_article_illegal_path(id: article.id)
```

PS: I haven't tested this code, so there might be the odd spelling error, but it works theoretically at least.

There is an interesting article on this matter [here](http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get this error, when I implement your (first) solution: >> No route matches {:action=>"update_legality", :controller=>"articles", :id=>24, :illegal=>false} missing required keys: [:illegal] <<
... If I change the route to >> get '/update_article_legality' << (for debugging purposes), then the page loads, and I can see that the 'Make legal'-link links to this: 'update_article_legality?id=24&illegal=false'. But I'm unable to fix the error. :-/ Do you know what to do here?

Comment: Yeah of course, sorry, this is what happens when you can't test your code. See my update. It's because you cannot pass booleans to `link_to`. That's why I would prefer the 2nd solution.